# How to add history item from Redmine plugin using journal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, redmine, redmine-plugins

I have update the meeting plugin. in this plugin when update the meeting it doesnot update the meeting history. 
like i change the subject for meeting it update the subject but dont update the history like issue.

my configuration of redmine is as following

```
Environment:
  Redmine version                3.3.1.stable
  Ruby version                   2.1.5-p273 (2014-11-13) [x86_64-linux]
  Rails version                  4.2.7.1
  Environment                    development
  Database adapter               Mysql2
```

I have done following->

for my model class

```
 def init_journal(user, notes = "")
  @current_journal ||= Journal.new(:journalized => self, :user => user, :notes => notes, :notify => false)

    if new_record?
      @current_journal.notify = false
    else
      @attributes_before_change = attributes.dup
    end
    @current_journal
  end

  def last_journal_id
    if new_record?
      nil
    else
      journals.maximum(:id)
    end
  end

  # Returns a scope for journals that have an id greater than journal_id
  def journals_after(journal_id)
    scope = journals.reorder("#{Journal.table_name}.id ASC")
    if journal_id.present?
      scope = scope.where("#{Journal.table_name}.id > ?", journal_id.to_i)
    end
    scope
  end

  def create_journal
    if @current_journal
      # attributes changes
      if @attributes_before_change
        (Meeting.column_names - %w(id created_at updated_at)).each {|c|
          before = @attributes_before_change[c]
          after = send(c)
          next if before == after || (before.blank? && after.blank?)
          @current_journal.details << JournalDetail.new(:property => 'attr',
                                                        :prop_key => c,
                                                        :old_value => before,
                                                        :value => after)
        }
      end
      @current_journal.save
      # reset current journal
      init_journal @current_journal.user, @current_journal.notes
    end
  end
```

and for controller class

```
def update_meeting_from_params
    @edit_allowed = User.current.allowed_to?(:edit_meetings, @project)
    @time_entry = TimeEntry.new(:meeting => @meeting, :project => @meeting.project)
    @time_entry.attributes = params[:time_entry]

    @meeting.init_journal(User.current)

    meeting_attributes = params[:meeting]
    @meeting.safe_attributes = meeting_attributes
  end
```

I get following error.
    http://prntscr.com/eb257g
  please help me

Comment: Which Redmine version?

Comment: its is the latest version.

i update the question with my environment.

Comment: And which meetings plugin?

Comment: https://github.com/integra-consultores/meetings

Comment: That plugin is 4 years old and not compatible with latest redmine. Try other fork.

Comment: There is not other fork.

i make it compatible with latest verison but the jouranl is not working. all other work now

Comment: I have also use journal in other thing but it give same error

Comment: Not sure how to help you without having whole code, check this https://github.com/crosspath/journalized/blob/master/lib/journalized.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your journalized object (Meeting) should have a method called journalized_attribute_names

Try to add it to your model (meeting.rb):

```
# Returns the names of attributes that are journalized when updating the meeting
def journalized_attribute_names
  names = Meeting.column_names - %w(id created_on updated_on)
  names
end
```

Comment: Yes it work but i give another error like this.

undefined method `custom_field_values' for #<Meeting:0x00000005761600>

Comment: You should look at the "Issue" model and see how these methods are implemented. Then you just have to adapt and add them to your custom model (meeting).

Comment: I didnot find this method in the issue model

Comment: Thanks buddy i got that.. its not in the Issue model it is in the act_as_customizer.rb class.

Thanks for your help.. I stuck with these from last week.

Comment: Your model should probably mention "acts_as_customizable". Glad it helped ;)